# OpenCV - findChessboardCorners "occasionally" fails when detecting high resolution image?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

First of all, I understand this question has been asked several times at here.

[FindChessboardCorners cannot detect chessboard on very large images by long focal length lens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018620/findchessboardcorners-cannot-detect-chessboard-on-very-large-images-by-long-foca)

[Opencv corners detection for High resolution images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846076/opencv-corners-detection-for-high-resolution-images)

However, my situation is a little bit different.

My first experiment is retrieving sequential images of 3264 x 2448 from a Webcam which supports resolution this high, and uses findChessboardCorners to detect the corners on a pattern I placed.

Gladly it works! So I move to next experiment.(See success cases below, I cropped them)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

This time I try to project a pattern from a projector of my own to a clean board and detect it, Sadly I failed at here.(Example below, 2592 x 1944)

[image: 4]

The two experiments retrieves similar images(I think so), but how come one succeeds and the other one won't? Especially the succeed one has the highest resolution.

I also tried adjust the size of the pattern that projector projects, didn't work.

Adjust the distance of the board, didn't work.

Adjust the camera settings, from lighter to darker, didn't work.

By the way, I suppose the resolution I choose affects the camera intrinsic parameters, so "resize" the image shouldn't be a good idea right? Since I require parameters under high resolution.

Comment: see answer of @JavierBarandiaranMartirena at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993522/opencv-findchessboardcorners-function-is-failing-in-a-apparently-simple-scenar

Comment: (add a border if background is black)